# Base case specialization for recursive variadic template

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, boost-hana

My target is to define a `Recursive` class, templated on an `int N` and one or more types `T, ...Ts`, which should behave like a `std::pair` with

- a `std::array` of `N` items of type `T` as the `first`,
- and, as `second`, an ***optional*** `std::vector` of `Recursive` instances templated on the same `N` and on the remaining template arguments `Ts...`.

In trying to write down the class given the above requirements, I've come up with this non-working code (where I've also defined some necessary, as they help a lot, aliases for two instantiations of `Recursive`), and I don't know if I have mis-designed what I described above (or if it is an ill-formed description!), or if I'm misusing the language syntax.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <boost/hana/fwd/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/optional.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <int N, typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Ts>
struct Recursive
    : std::pair<std::array<T1, N>, 
                boost::hana::optional<std::vector<Recursive<N, T2, Ts...>>>> {};

template <int N, typename T>
struct Recursive<N, T> : std::array<T, N> {};

template<typename ...T>
using Recursive2 = Recursive<2u, T...>;

template<typename ...T>
using Recursive3 = Recursive<3u, T...>;

int main() {
    using boost::hana::nothing;
    Recursive2<int> x(std::make_pair(std::array<int, 2>{0,0}, nothing));
}
```

I'll add some troubleshooting that I've done so far. In the following the template specilization seems to work just fine.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <int N, typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct Recursive {
    void operator()(){ std::cout << "general\n"; }
};

template <int N, typename T>
struct Recursive<N, T> {
    void operator()(){ std::cout << "specialized\n"; }
};

template<typename ...T>
using Recursive2 = Recursive<2u, T...>;

template<typename ...T>
using Recursive3 = Recursive<3u, T...>;

int main() {
    Recursive2<int>{}();
    Recursive2<int>{}();
    Recursive2<int,int>{}();
}
```

Comment: Comment _a posteriori_: since `std::vector` **can** have zero elements, there's probably really no point in wrapping it in an optional; an empty `std::vector` already represents the end of the recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues:

- Your specialization doesn't match your primary template

  `template <int N, typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Ts> struct Recursive;` requires at least 3 parameters. I think it should be a specialization and primary template should be:

  ```
  template <int N, typename T1, typename ...Ts>
  struct Recursive;
  ```
- `template <int N, typename T> struct Recursive<N, T>` doesn't behave like a `std::pair` (as you state your requirement, else your usage is wrong), you probably want something like:

  ```
  template <int N, typename T>
  struct Recursive<N, T> : std::pair<std::array<T, N>, decltype(boost::hana::nothing)>
  ```
- You need to "forward" the constructors of the base class, (Composition instead of inheritance might be an option too, or traits to define type to use) or change way to construct the object.

Result is:

```
template <int N, typename T1, typename ...Ts>
struct Recursive;

template <int N, typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Ts>
struct Recursive<N, T1, T2, Ts...>
    : std::pair<std::array<T1, N>,
                boost::hana::optional<std::vector<Recursive<N, T2, Ts...>>>
                            >
{
    using std::pair<
        std::array<T1, N>,
        boost::hana::optional<std::vector<Recursive<N, T2, Ts...>>>>::pair;
};

template <int N, typename T>
struct Recursive<N, T>
    : std::pair<std::array<T, N>, decltype(boost::hana::nothing)>
{
    using std::pair<std::array<T, N>, decltype(boost::hana::nothing)>::pair;
};

template<typename ...T>
using Recursive2 = Recursive<2u, T...>;

template<typename ...T>
using Recursive3 = Recursive<3u, T...>;

int main() {
    using boost::hana::nothing;
    Recursive2<int> x(std::make_pair(std::array<int,2>{0,0}, nothing));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90e30964c9f9ceba)

Comment: +1. What are the `using` statements inside the two specialization? Plus, what part of your code you refer to, when you say I _need to forward the constructors of the base class_? Finally, are you keen to give a look at my self answer? I feel yours (well, also the other one) is better than mine, but maybe you could give a more specific opinion?

Comment: The `using Base::Base;` allows to reuse base constructor, and avoid to write constructor to forward to base class.

Comment: Wow, but that's amazing! So it is known as _inheriting contructors_, based on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration). So the last `pair` on the line is the costructor associated to the `std::pair` class. Mmm, very interesting and useful!

Comment: I have only one last comment on this (then I'll probably link off here a follow up question that I plan to ask, in case you want to look at that too). I think you can make the first specialization the primary template (by removing `T2` and removing `<N, T1, T2, Ts...>`) and it would work anyway ([verified](https://godbolt.org/z/5TzG6n)). Is this an oversight or was it intentional?

Comment: It turns out the follow up question is very loosely related, but maybe you want to give a look at it: [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64127498/automatic-conversion-from-derived-class-to-base-class-member-variables-type).

Comment: I used `T2` as you originally use it, not  remarked it was unneeded.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is that, first, you've declared `Recursive` receiving at least one integer and **two** or more types and, then, you've declared a partial specialization receiving one integer and exactly **one** type.

Error because the specialization can't receive only one type when the main template is declared receiving two types or more.

Can be counter-intuitive but a solution can be declare `Recursive` receiving only **one** type or more (and this become the ground case of the recursion) and the specialization receiving **two** types or more

```
template <int N, typename T1, typename...>
struct Recursive : std::array<T1, N>
 { };

template <int N, typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Ts>
struct Recursive<N, T1, T2, Ts...>
   : std::pair<std::array<T1, N>,
               boost::hana::optional<std::vector<Recursive<N, T2, Ts...>>>>
 { };
```

The following is little modified (`std::size_t` instead of `int` for sizes; `std::optional` instead of `boost::hana::optional`) but fully compiling example

```
#include <array>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <std::size_t N, typename T1, typename...>
struct Recursive : std::array<T1, N>
 { };

template <std::size_t N, typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Ts>
struct Recursive<N, T1, T2, Ts...>
   : std::pair<std::array<T1, N>,
               std::optional<std::vector<Recursive<N, T2, Ts...>>>>
 { };

template<typename ...T>
using Recursive2 = Recursive<2u, T...>;

template<typename ...T>
using Recursive3 = Recursive<3u, T...>;

int main ()
 {
    Recursive2<int> x{std::array<int, 2u>{0,0}};
    Recursive3<int, long> y{{std::array<int, 3u>{0,0,0}, {}}};
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding my own answer because I did find a solution (a bit before receiving the two answers; using `std::optional` is a late change I made accroding to one of the answers, though). However, in my solution I *had* to declare and define the constructor for the general and specialized templates, which makes me think it is not as good a solution as the other answers. But why not posting it?

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <int N, typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct Recursive : std::pair<std::array<T, N>,
                             std::optional<std::vector<Recursive<N, Ts...>>>
                   > {
    template<typename ...Args>
    Recursive(Args&& ...args) : std::pair<std::array<T, N>,
                                std::optional<std::vector<Recursive<N, Ts...>>>
                  >(args...) {}
};

template <int N, typename T>
struct Recursive<N, T> : std::array<T, N> {
    template<typename ...Args>
    Recursive(Args&& ...x) : std::array<T, N>(x...) {}
};


template<typename ...T>
using Recursive2 = Recursive<2u, T...>;

template<typename ...T>
using Recursive3 = Recursive<3u, T...>;

int main() {
    std::array<std::string, 2> twoStrings{"hello","Hello"};
    std::array<char, 2> twoChars{'h', 'H'};

    Recursive2<std::string> s{twoStrings};
    assert(s == twoStrings);

    std::vector<Recursive2<char>> vecOfTwoChars{twoChars, twoChars, twoChars};

    Recursive2<std::string, char> sc{twoStrings, vecOfTwoChars};
    assert(sc.first == twoStrings);
    assert(sc.second->size() == 3);
    assert(sc.second == vecOfTwoChars);
    assert(sc.second.value()[0] == twoChars);

}
```

Comment: Forwarding constructor has caveat, as it is better match than copy constructor for non const lvalue.

Comment: @Jarod42, whereas your solution of inheriting the base class' constructor does not have this or other weaknesses, right? I'll not delete my answer, as I think it can be instructive, especially thank to your comment. For the reader, searching in SO with `[c++11] [perfect-forwarding] "forwarding constructor"` gives a lot of good results.