# Automatic conversion from derived class to base class' member variable's type

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, derived-class, std-pair

Long story short: I'd like to understand why the `D::operator B() const` conversion operator is not used in the last line in the code below, which thus fails when compiling with `g++ -std=c++17 source.cpp` (compiling with `g++ -std=c++2a deleteme.cpp` is successful, though).

The error is:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 deleteme.cpp && ./a.out 
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/cassert:44,
                 from deleteme.cpp:1:
deleteme.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
deleteme.cpp:19:14: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘D’ and ‘B’)
   19 |     assert(d == B{2}); // conversion operator not invoked explicitly errors // LINE
      |            ~ ^~ ~~~~
      |            |    |
      |            D    B
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/utility:70,
                 from deleteme.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:466:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator==(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)’
  466 |     operator==(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:466:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/cassert:44,
                 from deleteme.cpp:1:
deleteme.cpp:19:20: note:   ‘B’ is not derived from ‘const std::pair<_T1, _T2>’
   19 |     assert(d == B{2}); // conversion operator not invoked explicitly errors // LINE
      |
```

The code is:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <utility>

struct B {
    int x;
    B(int x) : x(x) {}
    bool operator==(B const& other) const { return x == other.x; }
};

struct D : std::pair<B,char*> {
    operator B() const { return this->first; }
};

int main() {
    B b{1};
    D d{std::pair<B,char*>(B{2},(char*)"hello")};

    assert((B)d == B{2}); // conversion operator invoked explicitly is fine
    assert(d == B{2}); // conversion operator not invoked explicitly errors // LINE
}
```

This question is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64118868/5825294). There I got help to write a class `Recursive` which behaves like a pair (so inherits from it) whose `first` is a `std::array` and whose second is a `boost::hana::optional<std::vector<...>>` (see the link for details).

Since the `second` of the `std::pair` is kind of an "advanced" information to what's contained in the `first`, in many places I'd like to cast/convert this object of `std::pair`-like class `Recursive` to the type of its `first`.

Comment: @Holy http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68d497240770629f

Comment: Why d should be converted to B and not B{2} to D?

Comment: @mfnx, because I can slice away what makes `D` different from `B`, leveraging the fact that it has a `B` and something else (a `char*` for instance, I've slightly modified the code). Converting a `B` to a `D` would mean "inventing" a way to fill the `second` element of the `pair`.

Comment: I mean, how does the compiler know you want to convert d to type B and then compare (B)d with B{2} if you don't make that clear to the compiler?

Comment: @mfnx, well, since I provide one function to convert from `D` to `B` and no function to convert from `B` to `D`, the choice for me seems pretty easy. Why is the C++17 compiler so reluctant?

Comment: Your intuition is reasonable. And that is what will happen from c++20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When compiler sees `d == B{2}`, it first [creates a list of `operator==` overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Call_to_an_overloaded_operator) that it's able to find, and then performs overload resolution on them.

As the link explains, the overload list contains:

- Member `operator==`s of the first operand, if any.
- Non-member `operators==`s found by unqualified lookup, if any.
- Built-in `operator==`s, if your operands can be converted to built-in types.

There's no mention of examining conversion operators of the first operand, so your `operator==` doesn't get found.

The solution is to make the `operator==` non-member (possibly define it as a `friend`). This works:

```
friend bool operator==(const B &a, const B &b) {return a.x == b.x;}
```

---

Starting from C++20, the rules of comparison operators got relaxed: the compiler will look for member `operator==` in the second operand as well, and will happily call non-member `operator==` with arguments in a wrong order.

So `a == b` and `b == a` are now equivalent to a degree, except that:

- An `operator==` called in this new manner must return `bool`.
- If given choice, the compiler will prefer the old ways of calling `operator==` over calling the member `operator==` of the rhs, which is in turn preferred over calling a non-member `operator==` with a wrong argument order.

Comment: The answer is correct, but the last statement "... arguments in a wrong order" is a bit off. `==` *should* have always been symmetric, even as a member, so there is no *wrong* order. c++20 just fixes this hole. So "wrong order" should just be "any order" :)

Comment: @cigien Turns out they're not entirely equivalent, so in my edit I still have to differentiate between the original and the reversed order. I could've called it "reverse", but eh. :P